How to set TabView .tabBar background color?
I want to change the bottom tab bar background color to make it visible all the time. However it is only visible when I scroll down despite the .visible setting. Why?
NavigationStack {
    TabView {
        List(randomData) { randomItem in
            NavigationLink {
                RandomDetailView(randomItem: randomItem)
            } label: {
                Text(randomItem.randomLabel ?? "Untitled")
            }
        }
        .tabItem {
            Label("RandomTab", systemImage: "square.and.pencil")
        }
        .toolbar(.visible, for: .tabBar)
        .toolbarBackground(.red, for: .tabBar)

        Text("RandomText")
        .tabItem {
            Label("RandomTab", systemImage: "square.and.pencil")
        }
    }
}


You need to set .visible to the tab bar background to make it always show up. It is .hidden by default.
TabView {
   List()
       ...
       .toolbar(.visible, for: .tabBar)
       .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .tabBar) //<- here
       .toolbarBackground(.red, for: .tabBar)
}

Output


It works. Thanks! Awkward API design though.

Yeah I feel you, sometimes.
